# How to connect to mariadb from host with docker-compose

Tags: mysql, docker-compose, mariadb

I have this docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:latest
    container_name: mariadb
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - internal

  drupal:
    image: drupal:9.3.9-fpm-alpine
    container_name: drupal
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - internal
      - external
    volumes:
      - /var/www/html/:/var/www/html/

  webserver:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: webserver
    depends_on:
      - drupal
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/www/html/:/var/www/html/
      - ./nginx-conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    networks:
      - external

networks:
  external:
    driver: bridge
  internal:
   driver: bridge

volumes:
  db-data:
```

I run `docker-compose up -d` and everything works fine, but I can not access to the mariadb server from host, I tried these

```
# mysql -uroot -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

# mysql -uroot -p -h mariadb
Enter password: 
ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'mariadb' (-2)

# mysql -uroot -p -h 127.0.0.1
Enter password: 
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1:3306' (111)
```

Edit:
`.env` file:

```
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=abc1234
MYSQL_DATABASE=my_db
MYSQL_USER=drupal
MYSQL_PASSWORD=cdf1234
```

Comment: What do the container logs of the mariadb show? You'll notice `[Warning] 'default-authentication-plugin' is MySQL 5.6 / 5.7 compatible option. To be implemented in later versions`, as the `mysql_native_password` is still the default.

Answer (score 0):

From [MariaDB Docker Library documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb/);

> One of MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD, MARIADB_ALLOW_EMPTY_ROOT_PASSWORD, or
> MARIADB_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD (or equivalents, including *_FILE), is
> required. The other environment variables are optional.

This is for the initialization of the `db-data` volume. Once initialized, these environment variables are optional.

Comment: I added the env variables in the mariadb block: `env_file: .env`

Comment: Ok, only "One of"? A shared version could help, even with passwords changed.

Answer (score 0):

mysql port has not been opened/forwarded ports from host to mariadb container:

```
     version: "3"
    
    services:
      mariadb:
...
        networks:
          - internal
        ports:
          - "3306:3306"
    
      drupal:
...
```